# Making a frame of an asymmetrical shape with an even width in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes

I am trying to create a frame of a star. I have tried duplicating and shrinking a whole star, and placing it over the original and deleting it to leave the edge. However, it doesn't result in an even width. How would I go about creating this?

Comment: It's better using Illustrator for this. You can do it with Object - Path - Offset Path menu.

Comment: Hi Tim, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I will suggest:

1. Select the star shape with your favorite tool, like the magic wand, you will see the marching ants on the outside
2. Create a new blank layer while the selection is still active
3. Making sure the new layer is targeted, go to "Edit/Stroke" and add the desired stroke width, color, and whether it is on the inside, outside, or in the middle of the selection

This will give you just the outline and it will be exactly the width you like, an even width all around.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can try based on how the star was created.

If it is on it's own layer, you can Control+Click (WIN) or Command+Click (MAC) to select the star on that layer. From there you can go to the Select Menu > Modify > Contract and choose a couple of pixels. Heads up though, this will round points and corners if you do it too far in.

If it's on a one color background, use the Magic Wand to select outside it and do the same as above.

Another route if you have the star on it's own layer is to select the layer, go to the Layer menu > Layer Styles... > Stroke. Change the Position to Inside, select the color you want then click Blending Options on the left and set the Fill to 0%. Same result as above but you get a precise edge and the width you like and you can apply that to other items if you need the same frame for them as well. Just right click the little FX thing on the layer and copy the style then paste it on another layer as needed.